# Number sequence with a given formula

Tags: sequences-and-series, logarithms

$a_{n}$ is a sequence which is given by the formula: $a_{n+1}=\log_2(a_n)$, where $a_1=30$. What is a number of maximum elements of the sequence?
I tried to approximate each number but I think there must be more systematic way to solve this problem. Can you explain this to me? Note that sequence only contains real numbers.

Comment: Are you sure all the terms are real?

Comment: Yes, It's correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$16<30<65536.$$

Taking the logarithm once,

$$4<\log_230<16.$$

Twice,

$$2<\log_2\log_230<4.$$

Thrice,

$$1<\log_2\log_2\log_230<2.$$

Four times,

$$0<\log_2\log_2\log_2\log_230<1.$$

Five times,

$$\log_2\log_2\log_2\log_2\log_230<0.$$

Comment: So as I understand 7th wouldn't be because 6th term is negative. Thank you very much

Comment: @NikaChelidze: can you guess why I used $65536$ for the upper bound ?

Comment: I thought I understood it but I can't explain correctly I think.

Comment: @NikaChelidze: can you find the smallest $a_1$ such that the sequence can have one more term ?

Comment: I tried but I think that number is too big, Or I have some mistake in my calculations

Comment: What do you think?

Comment: @NikaChelidze: that you made a mistake.

Answer (score 2):

Notice that

$$a_2 = \log_2(a_1)$$
$$\implies 4<a_2<5$$
Taking the logarithm of each term,
$$\implies \log_2 4 < \log_2(a_2)<\log_25$$
$$\implies2<a_3<3$$
(As $\log_25 <3$)

If you keep taking the logarithm, you'll finally get:
$$-\infty <a_6<0$$

So $a_6$ will be the last term in the series.

Answer (score 0):

Note sure what you are asking. If you are assuming $a_n \in \mathbb{C}$, then the sequence has an infinite number of terms (but you have to define the log branch you are using).

If you are assuming $a_n \in \mathbb{R}$, note the terms are decreasing quickly. What happens to $a_{n+1}$ when $a_n < 1$?

Comment: This question was used on the Georgian National Exam. So I know only that what they are asking.